# Django csrf_token error, while I wrote it

Tags: python, django, csrf-token

Django csrf_token error, while I wrote it in my HTML file, but why does this error message poped up when I wrote that `csrf_token`?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    {% load static %}
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'f/ask/ask.css' %}">
        <title>BareTalk</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block content %}
            <div id="wrapper">
                
                <form method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form }}
    
                    <!-- TODO: input submit Reg() function javascript -->
                    <button name="final" id="final">Ask</button>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
    <script src="{% static 'f/ask/ask.js' %}"></script>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste this code and try again ->

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        {% load static %}
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'f/ask/ask.css' %}">
            <title>BareTalk</title>
        </head>
        <body>
                <div id="wrapper">
                    
                    <form method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{ form }}
        
                        <!-- TODO: input submit Reg() function javascript -->
                        <button name="final" id="final">Ask</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
        </body>
        <script src="{% static 'f/ask/ask.js' %}"></script>
        </html>
```